# How to enable sound on HDMI?

Tags: raspbian, audio, hdmi

I have looked at all kinds of tutorials, I modified the `/boot/config.txt` by adding `hdmi_drive=2` and sound just does not work or if it does it always is over analog out.

I just want sound over HDMI to function. I used berryboot on my RPi 2 and tried some of the available distros. What I ended up doing is installing Raspbian then installing RetroPie because the retropie distro had issues with bluetooth, since I'm using a bluetooth controller this was not an option.

Is there a specific order for the `/boot/config.txt` file? I just added `hdmi_drive=2` to the end.

Thank you for all assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's another setting in your /boot/config.txt that affects sound: **hdmi_group**

If you want sound over HDMI, config.txt should have **both**:

hdmi_group=1

hdmi_drive=2

You need them both set because **hdmi_group=1** tells the kernel we are using CEA mode (for TV's, has sound) instead of DMT mode(for monitors, no sound) and 
**hdmi_drive=2** tells the kernel to use HDMI if available. (HDMI mode has sound, DVI does not.)

If that doesn't work, verify that your snd-bcm2835 module being is loaded on boot (/etc/modules) and not blacklisted...

Comment: This worked for my HDMI TV.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file /boot/config.txt.

Change this part of the file to make it matching with the proposal below :

```
# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in DMT (computer monitor) modes
hdmi_drive=2
```

Comment: hdmi_drive=2 worked for me.